# Defining a user verification interface with optional credentials

Tags: java, oop, interface

In my application there should be two ways to log-in: Manually via user/password or automatically, where the credentials are retrieved from the operating system (connected to an active directory server).

In order to be flexible, I have created a new interface:

```
interface SignOnProcessor { 
  boolean verifyLogin(SignOnCredentials _credentials)
}
```

where `SignOnCredentials` is an interface without any methods.

After that, I have created two implementations of `SignOnProcessor`: `PasswordSignOnProcessor` and `SingleSignOnProcessor`. Both implement different logic in their `verifyLogin()` method.

The `PasswordSignOnProcessor` needs the username and the password, therefore  `PasswordSignOnCredentials` is implemented like this:

```
class PasswordSignOnCredentials implements SignOnCredentials {
  String getUserName();
  String getPassword();
}
```

The `SingleSignOnProcessor`, on the other hand, does not need any credentials. It will just ask the operating system for the necessary information. Therefore I am currently passing an empty implementation of the `SignOnCredentials`:

```
class SingleSignOnCredentials implements SignOnCredentials {
  // Nothing here, credentials are retrieved from OS
}
```

Nothing is done with the `SingleSignOnCredentials` in the `verifyLogin()` method.

I have the feeling there must be a nicer way. I should not need to create and pass an object to `verifyLogin()` and then not use it.
Another solution I could think of is to create an interface method `verifyLogin()` without any parameters. That also doesn't feel right.

What is the preferred solution in this situation? There should be some nice, clean way of doing this, but currently I am stuck. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see another problem. Take this example:

```
SignOnProcessor sop = new PasswordSignOnCredentials();
sop.verifyLogin(new SingleSignOnCredentials());
```

Because this is possible, you'd have to typecheck the credentials object in your implementation. What you want to do is generalize two methods who actually have different parameters. Even if you wrap the parameters in an object an generalize that object too, this is the case.

Since I don't know your calling code I assume that you always know which implementation is called anyway (meaning you don't rely on some dynamic binding magic). In this case I have two possible solutions:

In my opinion the right way to go really is creating two operations. In this case you would have a single implementation of `SignOnProcessor` that can do both. Maybe you could also name them differently.

Another way to go would apply if all your (future) implementations need either the same parameters or none at all. I think it's okay to not use the parameters in some of the implementations. You could pass `null` as actual parameter if you use the SSO.

Still both options don't feel perfect to me either but I don't think it's compulsory bad style (depending on your calling code). But I'd like to hear some other answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to "be flexible"? **Creating fancy interfaces just for the sake of it is not a good idea**. Try to solve your problem in the simplest way possible instead and see how it goes.

It's hard to suggest anything, since you haven't specified how does you application actually choose which method to call, as André Stannek has already pointed out.